# Apple Mach-O Linker Error (linker command failed with exit code 1)

Tags: objective-c, ios

When attempting to run my test class i get the following error

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Client", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in eFit2Tests.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

"_OBJC_CLASS_$_Client", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in eFit2Tests.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Here is the method declaration for the constructor which is giving the error

## import "Client.h"

@implementation Client

```
-(id)init
{
    if(self = [super init]) {

    firstName = @"Unknown First Name";
    lastName = @"Unknown Last Name";
    birthday = [NSDate date];

    // create weight array
    weight = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:1];

    workoutSkeletons = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:1];
}
return self;
```

}

here is the test case that is giving the error

```
#import "eFit2Tests.h"
#import "Set.h"
#import "Exercise.h"
#import "Workout.h"
#import "Client.h"
#import "Library.h"

@implementation eFit2Tests

- (void)testClientInit
{
Client* test = [[Client alloc] init];

/**
if([test fullName] != @"Unknown First Name Unknown Last Name") {
    STFail(@"Name not currectly initialized. (init (Client))");
}
if([test weight] != 0) {
    STFail(@"Weight not currectly initialized. (init (Client))");
}
 */
```

}

As far as I can tell I have implemented and tested all of my classes the same way however this is the only one which gives me an error. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When I was checking the compiled sources I was looking at the wrong target. Oops...